# Out of Memory Exception while loading data into List

Tags: java, google-maps, ejb, out-of-memory, heatmap

I am trying to generate the heatmap on a googlemap, with around 2 million points (latitude and longitude). My idea is to read the points from a table, and pass them to the google api in a List. The problem is, loading the 2 million points into the List is causing out of memory error in the EJB. Following is the line that gives me the error.

```
 List<Earthquakerisk> earthquakeRiskList = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ASTEXT(geomArea) as geomText, riskvalue,id FROM Earthquakerisk e",Earthquakerisk.class).getResultList();
```

What alternatives can be applied so as to read the points and load them into the map? I am using glassfish 3.2.2, jdk 1.7, jsf 2.2, ejb.

Comment: Maybe setting the initial capacity of the List<> should help :)

Comment: In this case you should try to use a pagination query > http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Pagination.2C_Max.2FFirst_Results

Comment: Thanks @Chechus. I'll try the pagination query and confirm the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections

Also, have you thought about creating your own implementation of [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)? Then you can retrieve the needed data on-demand when the iterator performs the next step.

Another option would be to split your dataset - like when you are doing pagination.